# Gradient fill SVG with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, svg, jquery-svg, radial-gradients

Is there a way to fill SVG with two or three gradient colors. Using following way I can fill a particular SVG path by one color. And radial gradient can be used but it cannot handle dynamic way. Colors need to define within SVG code. So I want to fill SVG path using two or three colors as a gradient as following way using jquery. And is there any possibility to do this using [keith-svg](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) plugin?

```
$("#canvas-area").click(function (event) {
      $(event.target).css('fill', _'#000');
})
```

Comment: Create a radialGradient dynamically.

Comment: @RobertLongson How to create it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS

Comment: as @RobertLongson said, you need to create the element https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_grad_linear.asp and use it for fill

Comment: Or use a CSS gradient: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Robert_Longson commented you can create dynamically the RadialGradient element and then apply it to the fill property:

*This is a very basic way and need to be **improved** in order to consider colors and different properties as variable*

```js
$("#canvas-area").click(function(event) {
  $('body').append('<svg id="grade-def"><defs><radialGradient id="grad" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%"><stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:red;stop-opacity:1" /><stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:blue;stop-opacity:1" /></radialGradient></defs></svg>');
  $(event.target).attr('fill', 'url(#grad)');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg height="150" width="400" id="canvas-area">
  <ellipse cx="200" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="#000" />
  <text fill="#ffffff" font-size="45" font-family="Verdana" x="150" y="86">
  SVG</text>
</svg>
```

You can also have your RadialGradient already defined and you simply change the colors and/or other properties:

```js
let colors = ["green", "orange", "yellow", "brown", "blue", "red", "pink"]

$("#canvas-area").click(function(event) {
  $(this).find('#grad stop').eq(0).css('stop-color', colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)]);
  $(this).find('#grad stop').eq(1).css('stop-color', colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)]);
  $(event.target).attr('fill', 'url(#grad)');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg height="150" width="400" id="canvas-area">
<defs>
<radialGradient id="grad" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:red;stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:blue;stop-opacity:1" />
    </radialGradient>
</defs>
  <ellipse cx="200" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="#000" />
  <text fill="#ffffff" font-size="45" font-family="Verdana" x="150" y="86">
  SVG</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Actually I want to use radialGradient in dynamic way without defining radialGradient within SVG code.

Comment: @isuru can you be more precise ? :) as here i changed the color by i can dynamically  create the whole gradient element